# Use an ARM-template generated host as build agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Azure devops with it's pipelines is fine to generate automate your builds.
As far as I see, you can use

- MS hosted agents for your jobs
- Self hosted agents where you install the agent daemon

With Azure itself you can use ARM Template to build up machines on demand. It is pretty easy to use arm within [your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/deploy-arm-template?view=azure-devops).

In my opinion it would be great, if I could build an agent-machine within a pipeline with an arm template and use that agent for the further build process. With that solution we could make use of all the cool pipeline-yaml-features (scripts, conditions, ....).

Is there a solution that connects azure devops with azure in that way?

Answer (score 0):

that wont really work, as you need an agent to run the template in the first place, so it doesnt make a lot of sense. what problem are you trying to solve with this approach apart from it being cool?

Comment: the sense in my case, that I need a very special machine setup for the build I could provide that with a static installation somewehere (e.g. with the azure cloud).
But it would make much more sense to provide the infrastructure on demand, when the pipeline runs.

Comment: whats wrong with using a container? you cant really provide agents on demand (at least not without some hacks), hosted agents are meant to fill that gap

Comment: windows and a very special environment that is much easier to provide via arm than within containers (gone that way already and the arm solution would be much easier to use and maintain).

Comment: windows containers do exist. anyway, you can use a hosted agent with container or self-hosted agent. to provide an agent dynamically you have to have a first step that run on a hosted agent and run that template or whatever you are using to deploy the agent and then the actual step that runs on the agent. but that will make your builds 20 minutes longer, so it is a lot easier to just turn the vm on and let it sit there (you can reduce costs in multiple ways if thats what you are after). the time develop(s) have to wait costs 10x more whatever you will be paying for that vm to be online 24\7

Comment: all-in-all I dont think this is of any level of reason. time you will invest into building this solution will probably never be recuperated by the saving (in terms of your `time x your salary` vs `potential saving`)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this could be achievable.

ARM template supports to create VM and install Azure Devops agents at the same time.

Here is the [ARM template Json file sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-vsts-agent).

In Azure Pipeline, you need to add two agent job.

Agent Job1 : You need to use an existing agent to run the `ARM template deployment`
task.

Agent Job2:  You can specify a custom agent pool and add demands. (The ARM sample creates the agent in the `Default` agent pool by default)

For example:

[image]

In this case, you can specify agnet job to run tasks in the newly created agnet.

But as 4c74356b41 said, this may waste some resources.

Comment: sounds pretty near the solution, that would be fine for my use case.
unfortunately the template fails with `VMExtensionProvisioningError: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'vstsAgent'. Error message: "Failed to download all specified files. Exiting. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."`

Comment: also with configured dns the error persists. Does the template work on your site?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested this arm template yet. I just feel that your ideas are available. This answer is my personal opinion. I will test it and share the results